# Приоритет причин закрытия

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия

Иногда возникает такая ситуация: довольно плохой вопрос (например, учебное задание) ещё и является дубликатом.

**Вопрос:** с какой причиной голосовать за закрытие? *дубликат* или *учебное задание*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дубликат приоритетнее, так как он более эффективно позволяет найти решение будущим посетителям.

Мы не создаём решения для учеников, которые просто приносят задания не пытаясь решать, но если уж решение есть, то никто не запрещает в него посмотреть.

Альтернативно можно дать ссылку на дубликат в комментарии, а вопрос закрыть как учебное задание без попыток решения. Способ выбирайте в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: Дубликат приоритетнее всегда, или только для учебных заданий?

Comment: @wchistow в общем случае всегда.